# If the Eldritch Knight fighter's bonded weapon hits a creature, could that creature teleport with the weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, fighter, teleportation, eldritch-knight

The [Eldritch Knight fighter's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight) Weapon Bond feature states (*PHB* page 74):

> [...] If it is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand. [...]

If you hit a creature with a Bonded weapon, would they teleport when you summoned the weapon?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 8):

### Your weapon can't teleport anything else with it.

Rules elements like class features are specific about what they do.  If it says the weapon teleports to your hand, then *the weapon* does that, not anything it's sitting on, near, or in. (There's a potentially interesting argument about whether the sword leaves behind anything that was spread on the blade, like say blood or rust.)

If the effect could bring a creature with it, then it would say so.

There are no hidden rules.

Comment: I'd say that rust would be a part of the blade, rather than something applied to it.

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to *have* that argument, especially in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

### No, the creature would not be teleported with the weapon.

[Spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), and the same is true of class features; it would only teleport your weapon to your hand, not anyone holding it, using it, stabbed by it, etc.

Note that it does not say "the weapon teleports *as if* it used the spell *teleport*" or something similar, so we default to a normal interpretation of the sentence.

Comment: The risk of a too repeated phrase methinks, but there is no spell involved so you may wish reword your opening

Comment: Notably, this is a class feature, not a spell